# Duplication in documentation, example C# vs .NET Framework

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics

I can see duplication in [C# Language](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/topics) and [.NET Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/topics).

An easy one to spot is the [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) topic.

How do we handle duplication like that? (this can apply to many other documentation / topics)

Comment: Agree this can be improved. I'm seeing the same issue in the "MS SQL Server" and "SQL" topics. There's a lot of overlap materializing. It's all good information, but how does it get organized to prevent duplication?

Comment: There's a dupe with relevant answers over here. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329977/confusion-between-net-and-c-tags

Comment: I tried to start [a topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329171/3764814) about this issue in general, but looks like no one has a clue how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of marking as duplicate as per the [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328600/1663001) by @dorukayhan, maybe we could take the same concept as we have for tag synonyms. That way the topics are accessible from both parent tags and can be shared without duplication.

Comment: C# is a language, .NET is a framework. These are two *different* things in nature.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Yes I realise this, but I'm talking about specific topic or even just examples, not the entire tag. We already have synonyms for tags in the main SO system.

Comment: Yes but my point is that the C# tag should concentrate on the language, it should not be cluttered with .NET API examples.

Comment: There's always going to be some sort of clutter, that is unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, why not add a way to mark them as duplicates of other resources, just as we do on the actual Q&A site?

We can start this by letting users with gold tag badges use their [dupehammer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/dupehammer/info)s on Documentation<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1 - This would give top users (especially Jon Skeet) the power to mark every topic in pretty much all popular tags as dupes of other topics. But since they're already supposed to know what they're doing, it's not a thing to worry about.</sup>

Comment: But C# and .NET *aren't* duplicate concepts, they just share a lot of common information *while also having information that is specific to just that concept*.  While it may be useful in other contexts to have the ability to actually mark entire concepts as duplicates, it wouldn't address this specific problem.

Comment: Arguably, there is little point in having Documentation for .NET at all, @Servy. They tell us the whole point of Documentation is code examples, so you immediately run into the problem of choosing a language. Which one do you pick for .NET? Seems to me you're better off just documenting the .NET API for each of the different languages that it can target. That's certainly redundant, but less redundant and more sensible than documenting it *twice* for each language, once in the language tag and once in the generic .NET tag.

Comment: @CodyGray It's true that in order to write an example, you need to choose a programming language (or write in multiple languages). But in language-agnostic topics like LINQ methods, the actual language being used is (relatively) incidental to the example of the API itself -- `new List<int>() {1,2,3,4}.Where(x => x>2)` and `(New List<Integer>() From {1,2,3,4}).Where(Function(x) x>2)` are exactly the same example of the API, even though they are in different languages.