# To what extent are third-party libraries on topic in Documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation

As I asked in the comments in [this change request](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/35270?draftId=31209#commentId=4745), what is on-topic and what is off-topic as far as examples explaining how to use third-party libraries on Documentation? From my comment: "[W]here [do we] draw the line on what should be included in Documentation and what should not[?] Are other multiplexers from other libraries on topic? Are examples of a library that someone made on Github yesterday that has 1 star on topic?"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Language tags should document ... the language. Not libraries. Not APIs that are commonly used with the language.

For instance, right now the [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/topics) tag is a mess of actual language features (like [Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/197/classes) or [Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/187/arrays)) and other tangentially related things like DOM-related features like [2D Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/525/2d-canvas) and, well, [DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/503/document-object-model-dom), and Browser-related features like [Web Cryptography](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/761/web-cryptography-api#t=201607222202502066593) and [Web Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/428/web-storage).

The language should be documented as it is, not the environment in which is is used. Otherwise, continuing with the example, JavaScript will contain everything under the Node.js umbrella, all of the HTML5 APIs, and maybe the attempts to embed JavaScript in devices, because, hey, it's JavaScript.

Comment: Where else would you document array functionalities, and dom-related JavaScript features, if not in JavaScript? Node.js is a completely different subset, and libraries also shouldn't be added to the JS documentation, but  when you say "I know JavaScript", everyone assumes you're familiar with DOM manipulation.

Comment: The DOM should be documented in the DOM tag. The note about classes and arrays was meant to be the "good" to be contrasted against the following "bad" things. I agree that people make assumptions. The question we face on Documentation is whether we document assumptions or reality. I prefer the latter.

Comment: Isn't the DOM well enough documented on MDN? I thought the mission for documentation was to improve docs that are otherwise not good enough and not to increase fragmentation?

Comment: @ivarni that's a different question than the one this post answered.

Comment: It's a reply to a comment, not the answer. I see I forgot to tag it and it's too late to edit.

Comment: Well to respond to the comment, sure, the DOM is well documented, although I'd say the examples are not always great. And apparently it's all about examples on Docs...

Comment: "*The language should be documented as it is, not the environment in which is is used.*" While I agree with this in general, in the specific case of JavaScript, I have to disagree. 99% of all users of JavaScript are using it in a browser. Oh sure, there are some standalone apps that use it as their scripting language of choice. But for the *vast majority* of users, JavaScript == browser. From a practical perspective, it seems absurd to separate JavaScript documentation from the environment for which it was *created*.

Comment: @NicolBolas That's a valid point (though I doubt the actual number is 99% you're probably right about the *vast majority* part). But then, how many javascript users today actually interact with the DOM directly? I'd say "few" since I don't have numbers but from my experience most devs are using some framework that abstracts the DOM away so how useful is it really to document it under the Javascript Language topic?

Comment: My main gripe right now is the sheer number of topics under any given tag. It's a mess, like this answer points out, and it's hard to get an overview of actual language topics because they're intermixed with stuff like DOM features and browser APIs. It makes it hard for someone to find what's already documented and what's not.

Comment: @ivarni: "*it's hard to get an overview of actual language topics because they're intermixed with stuff like DOM features and browser APIs.*" To me, the best way to fix that is to give us real ways to categorize things into more than just topics and examples.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes! That's what I want too. But I think we should still be able to have a link to that "sub-section" or whatever it would be called from the actual tag on SO main. To me good documentation is good if it's both well written and easy to find. With peer-review I think SO documentation can eventually provide the first but as it is now can't possibly provide the second.

Comment: @NicolBolas You may very well believe that 99% of JavaScript occurs in a browser, or perhaps that's hyperbole. I think that as JavaScript matures, there will be more an more places where JavaScript will be used outside of the browser. It's already got the incredibly fast-growing Node.js environment.

Comment: @NicolBolas Additionally, with the advent of Web Assembly, other languages will be able to access the DOM and be used with browsers. Why limit examples for the DOM to only being written in JavaScript?

Comment: You should totally drop that and use jQuery... and I'm not joking!

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: why make a topic about DOM with a load of examples for the growing list of languages, instead of a DOM section for the specific language? If I'm looking for JS DOM stuff, I don't want to be bothered with examples for other languages.

Comment: @Cerbrus It's all a matter of where you want to draw the line when it comes to language tags. It appears as though you'd like to draw the line around "what can I do with this language". I'm of the opinion that it should document the language, and that's it. The examples will show what's possible with the language alone. If you want to show what can be done with environments, APIs, libraries, and frameworks, I'd prefer those to be in separate tags. Otherwise, I see inconsistency in including DOM, but not Node.js (as an example). See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328589/215552

Comment: Node.js Is a topic on it's own, because it's a _completely_ different topic. It's a server-side language that has a crapload of extra config / functionalities. Every single JavaScript documentation / tutorial site out there explains DOM features. It's a integral part of the language. There is absolutely no point in splitting out DOM from the JavaScript topic, other than adding more confusing separation. Node on the other hand is simply too large not to be a topic on it's own.

Comment: @Cerbrus Apparently Node.js (not to mention things built with Rhino, Nashorn, etc., and MongoDB, and OpenOffice [as a scripting language]) gets along quite well without the DOM, and uses JavaScript, so I'm not sure we have the same definition of "integral". Of course, JavaScript was, very early on, used as a server-side language by Netscape, presumably without a DOM. It seems like you really want DOM and JavaScript to get married, but honestly, they're just good friends ;)

Comment: _"It seems like you really want DOM and JavaScript to get married"_ Come on... Really?

Answer (score 4):

(Disclaimer: I'm the creator of the linked change request.)

To me, this issue is fairly clear. Documentation needs to be useful, and in order for it to be useful, it needs to provide documentation for the topics people need.

Many small libraries and addons don't warrant their own sections under Documentation. They're simply not large enough. [Pircbot](http://www.jibble.org/pircbot.php), the [Gorilla Toolkit](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/), and [LuaSocket](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/) are three examples I'd pull off the top of my head. Creating an entire section for a library as small and single-track as LuaSocket would be absurd - it would have one page, and that would be it. There simply wouldn't be more to add, even if someone wanted to.

But if we want this feature to be useful, it needs to document commonly-used libraries *somewhere*. That's basically the entire point - to help people by providing examples of how to do common tasks.

If someone creates an extra page under a topic for a library that's never used - that's fine. Maybe some day someone will search and find it, or maybe it'll never come up again. But barring all third party libraries prohibits an entire class of documentation information that is both useful and pertinent to a developer's searches.

If a library or project, like OpenCV, gets large enough, then it probably warrants separating off. But if it's too small to fit on its own, I'd rather have good documentation under the language documents than leave it off entirely - particularly for commonly-used tools for their specific purposes, like the ones I mentioned above.

Comment: There's got to be a reason there are requirements for how popular a tag is before it can have a topic on documentation and I would suspect that is because there is no point in SO maintaining documentation for libraries that hardly anyone use. If there was a need for documentation here there'd be enough activity in the tag for it to have its own topic. If not, well, then that documentation should rather sit in the README.md at GitHub than pollute the namespace of the language its written for.

Comment: @ivarni I think the error here is in thinking that documenting third party libraries will somehow detract from the documentation of core language features, which is simply not the case. A well written third party document wouldn't "pollute" Documentation.

Comment: "*Creating an entire section for a library as small and single-track as LuaSocket would be absurd*" I disagree. LuaSocket is not *small*. It may be "single-track", but it's got *lots* of features. To truly document LuaSocket would require dozens of topics.

Comment: @Emrakul I tend to disagree but the problem might simply be that we don't have the option to nest examples. If there could be a sub-topic called LuaSocket and we could add examples under that then it would alleviate some of the problem, but if we need *"dozens of topics"* to do it and they would be mixed with everything else then it makes for a very cluttered frontpage. I don't think it scales. You'd have a hard time finding anything unless you already knew where it was.

Comment: I can see no actual problem caused by a subject -- such as your example LuaSocket -- having only one sub-item.

Answer (score -1):

IMHO we should include the examples of small libraries unless they have their own topics or if we are thinking about drawing the line stictly, create topics for everything. But if we create a new topic for every library, we'll need someone to maintain it dedicately too.

So, the best option is to allow libraries to be included in the language/platform topic. This doesn't mean we should put `Node.js` in `JavaScript`, because `Node.js` has it's own topic. But we can include `Express` in `Node.js`, until `Express` have it's own topic. Same with `Passport`.

Another example would be with `ButterKnife`. It'll be gross misuse of resources, if we'll create it's own topic separate from `Android`. So does it mean we should exclude ButterKnife altogether, provided how useful it is in saving a lot of time of developers.

That also mean we should have some way to transfer examples to new topic whenever it gets created.

Comment: You're using the word "topic" but I think you mean "Tag", since that's the top-level grouping in Docs. "Topic"s are the second level.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Documentation lingo is still not clear to me.

Comment: Nor to me, honestly!