# Confusion between .NET docs and .NET-language docs

Tags: discussion, documentation

While trying to navigate through the C# Documentation dashboard, I came across a [proposed change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/64048):

[image]

Well, I absolutely agree with this comment, neither the [BCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Libraries_(CLI)#Base_Class_Library) nor the [FCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framework_Class_Library) are C# stuff. This belongs to the .Net tag, not the C# one (or we should also write them to VB.Net, etc...).

That being said, **what should we do**? Delete all the .Net related stuff from the C# tag ? Move it ? Currently I would say **more than 60% of the C# topics are actually .Net topics**.

Some random examples that *should* belong to the .Net tag, not the C# one:

- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/1587/datetime-methods#t=2016072816050032939
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/3114/stream#t=201607281605189402912
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/1588/backgroundworker#t=201607281605018451385
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/1192/singleton-implementation#t=201607281607014642644
- Etc.

---

EDIT

Seems to me that 80% of the VB.Net topics have the exact same issue.

I assume this applies to a lot of tags too, so this is more a general question than something related to .Net/C# only. If someone has a better, *more generic* title for this question, please make an edit.

Comment: Moving seems the best option here, but I think it might be quite an uphill struggle as it's likely that topics will get re-created a few times.  There's even a request at the moment for a C# documentation entry on RhinoMocks.

Comment: We have a closely-related challenge [for Apple platforms](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329306/reorganizing-documentation-sections-regarding-apple-technologies) and I thought I had seen somebody talking about JS ecosystem organization too.

Comment: I'm a bit reluctant to _move 60% of the second most important tag_. I think this is a general issue about tags organisation.

Comment: Yeah. you might as well re-tag 60% of the c# questions to .Net.

Comment: IIRC one of the things they would add in the next release of docs was per language examples. So then you can have BackgroundWorker with VB.Net and C# examples. And I think that is the reason now that stuff is where it is.

Comment: Got the same issue with JavaScript and the DOM/BOM/Web APIs. They were talking about adding the ability to move topics from one tag to another, but I believe a community manager or dev has to do them.

Comment: Here it is: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329557/documentation-update-july-25th

Answer (score 5):

The solution to this problem was just not quite ready yet. Essentially what the .NET articles need (and what many other similar situations need) is the *availability to give code snippets in multiple languages* without cluttering the whole example.

The multiple language feature was announced as delayed with the public beta meta post [Documentation Has Entered Public Beta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328405/1026459)

> **What’s to come**
>
> There are things we know we’re going to do that just weren’t ready in time for launch.
>
> - Code blocks with multiple languages (think MSDN’s C#/VB/F# switcher)

[image]

<sub>(source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)</sub>

This would allow for parent topics such as .NET to have several code snippets in one example, and I think that will reduce a lot of redundancy of both needing the language tag to have the same code as the library tag.

Comment: Great! But does this mean all those C# topics will be moved to the .Net tag? In the meantime, what should be done for such topics?

Comment: Well, hopefully the feature comes out soon. I don't really have a solid solution for what to do right this instant aside from attempting to trim content in the future once merging and multi language code snippets are available.

Comment: Can't wait to see this in action on Design Patterns, where we'll have > 20 languages in that tab grouping</sarcasm>

Comment: What do you suggest as the best way to go forward? Because I just dismissed [Remoting](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/topic-requests/4792). Not sure if my action is correct reading your answer.

Comment: @rene - My suggestion would be to allow excessive content creation and then once the tools to trim it arrive we can go about organizing it a bit more. Just getting content out there at the moment seems to be beneficial, and from the examples I have seen just browsing around, I like what is already present.

Comment: @rene - That said, I know that we are supposed to be quality over quantity and so there should be some middle ground. Striking the balance will be the hard part, but I think erring on the quantity side since it just started may be okay for a few weeks.

Comment: Ok, makes sense to me and is actionable. I'll go forward using your advice. Thanks